# Unable to access member function in a vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to simply create a vector of objects, add an object to it, and then display some variables in that object in the vector by accessing the function "getter's".  Code compiles but it shows nothing for functions that return string and a garbage number for the ones that return double.  I am sure it is something simple....can you help (assignment due in a couple of hours :S)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
    string fName, lName;
    double weeklyIncome, grossSales, bonus;
public:
    Employee(){};
    Employee(string fn, string ln, double sales)
    {
        fName = fn;
        lName = ln;
        grossSales = sales;
        bonus = sales * 0.09;
        weeklyIncome = 200;
    }
    double getNetIncome() {return bonus + weeklyIncome;}
    string getfName() {return fName;}
    double getgrossSales() {return grossSales;}
    ~Employee(){};
};

int main()
{
    vector<Employee> salespeople(15);
    Employee e1("John", "Smith", 5000);
    salespeople.push_back(e1);
    cout << salespeople[0].getNetIncome();
    cout << salespeople[0].getgrossSales();
    cout << salespeople[0].getfName();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<Employee> salespeople(15);      // This creates a vector of 15 elements
Employee e1("John", "Smith", 5000);
salespeople.push_back(e1);             // Now you have added the 16-th element
cout << salespeople[0].getNetIncome(); // The first element is still the default
                                       // constructed element.
cout << salespeople[0].getgrossSales();
cout << salespeople[0].getfName();
```

You can fix the problem by using

```
vector<Employee> salespeople;  // Create an empty vector and then
                               // add items to it.
```

or by changing

```
salespeople.push_back(e1);
```

to

```
salespeople[0] = e1;
```

**Suggestion for improvement**

Change the default constructor to initialize the `double` variables to sane values.

```
Employee() : weeklyIncome(0.0), grossSales(0.0) bonus(0.0) {};
```

Comment: To make sure that the vector is not "reallocated" before it has more than 15 elements, initialize the vector empty and then call `std::vector::reserve(size_type)` on it (`salespeople.reserve(15)`).

Comment: I knew it was something simple!  Thanks as always